# Not receiving Location Updates in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gps, location

I have two classes "GPSTracker" and "Live".
The GPSTracker has the GPS related functions i.e. to get the latitude and the longitude, while the Live class calls it to get the current Latitude and the Longitude and then calculate the distance travelled.
My problem is that I am not getting any changes in the location, the location remains at whatever it is at the start! No locationUpdates!

GPSTracker.java:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener 
{

private final Context mContext;
// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES =5; // 5 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 5; // 5 seconds

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) 
{
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() 
{
    try 
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) 
        {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else 
        {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) 
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) 
                {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) 
                    {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) 
            {
                if (location == null) 
                {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) 
                    {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) 
                        {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS()
{
    if(locationManager != null)
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude()
{
    if(location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude()
{
    if(location != null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() 
{
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is not enabled");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Enable location services to determine your location.");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
{
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
{
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
{
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
{
    return null;
}

}
```

Live.java:

```
public class Live extends Activity implements LocationListener
{   
GPSTracker gps;
Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
Location oldLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
float distanceTravelled=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live);
    startactivity();

}

public void startactivity() 
{

    gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);

    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is: \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);    
    }
    else
    {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }

}

public void resumeactivity() 
{

    gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);
    if(gps.canGetLocation())
    {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
        newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    }
    else
    {

    }
}

public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
    resumeactivity();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    oldLocation.set(newLocation);
    newLocation.set(location);
    //resumeactivity();
    distanceTravelled+=newLocation.distanceTo(oldLocation);
    String stringDistance= Float.toString(distanceTravelled);
    TextView distance = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textDistance);
    distance.setText(stringDistance);
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) 
{
    GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(Live.this);
    gps.showSettingsAlert();

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) 
{


}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) 
{


}
```

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but are you moving the device a far enough distance? Location updates only happen within a certain minimum threshold which might be larger than you think.

Comment: Yea, I try it while driving!

Answer (score 2):

I was facing same problem with my app, so what I did is reboot phone and Start the app under clear sky. It will might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a working example [here](http://www.stefreitag.de/wp/2013/09/19/auslesen-der-geo-position-beim-motorola-defy/). It is not calculating the distance, but this should be easy to add.